# This code is supposed to generate random different time for each scenario. But, I'm getting the same time. Is there a better way of doing this?

Tags: python

I tired to use if statement but don't think that's the best approach.

```py
import datetime
from random import randrange
    
hours = randrange(1, 25)
minutes = randrange(1, 61)
seconds = randrange(1, 61)
    
print(f"First Time on {hours}:{minutes}:{seconds}")
print(f"First Time off {hours}:{minutes}:{seconds}")
print(f"Second Time on {hours}:{minutes}:{seconds}")
print(f"Second Time off {hours}:{minutes}:{seconds}")
```

Comment: I don't understand your issue - please try to explain what you are trying to do.

Comment: Nevermind I think I understand - to get a new random hour, minute and second each time, the `randrange` function must be recalled. This can be done in a `for` loop, for example.

Answer (score 0):

I guess you are trying to print different times for "First Time On", "First Time Off", "Second Time on" and "Second Time off"

The issue with your code is

These three lines generate three random numbers from the given ranges, but that happens only once.

```
hours = randrange(1, 25)
minutes = randrange(1, 61)
seconds = randrange(1, 61)
```

After that, you are printing the same numbers without regenerating them.

```
print(f"First Time on {hours}:{minutes}:{seconds}")
print(f"First Time off {hours}:{minutes}:{seconds}")
print(f"Second Time on {hours}:{minutes}:{seconds}")
print(f"Second Time off {hours}:{minutes}:{seconds}")
```

So you need to call `randrange` everytime you want a new time

```py
import datetime 
from random import randrange
hours = randrange(1, 25)
minutes = randrange(1, 61)
seconds = randrange(1, 61)

print(f"First Time on {hours}:{minutes}:{seconds}")

hours = randrange(1, 25)
minutes = randrange(1, 61)
seconds = randrange(1, 61)
print(f"First Time off {hours}:{minutes}:{seconds}")

hours = randrange(1, 25)
minutes = randrange(1, 61)
seconds = randrange(1, 61)
print(f"Second Time on {hours}:{minutes}:{seconds}")

hours = randrange(1, 25)
minutes = randrange(1, 61)
seconds = randrange(1, 61)
print(f"Second Time off {hours}:{minutes}:{seconds}")
```

Answer (score 0):

If what you are trying to do is to print a different hour, minute and second, a loop like so can be used:

```
import datetime 
from random import randrange

onoff = ["First Time on", "First time off", "Second time on", "Second time off"]

for currentonoff in onoff:
    hours = randrange(1, 25)
    minutes = randrange(1, 61)
    seconds = randrange(1, 61)
    print(currentonoff + " " + str(hours) + ":" + str(minutes) + ":" + str(seconds))
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to run the generator everytime you want a new random time.

```
import datetime 
from random import randrange

def random_time():
    hours = randrange(1, 25)
    minutes = randrange(1, 61)
    seconds = randrange(1, 61)
    return hours, minutes, seconds

for i in range(3):
    hours, minutes, seconds = random_time()
    print(f"Second Time on {hours}:{minutes}:{seconds}")
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to do the randomization for each line.

```
from random import randrange

def get_random_time():
    return randrange(0, 24), randrange(0, 60), randrange(0, 60)


messages = [
    'First time on',
    'First time off',
    'Second time on',
    'Second time off',
]

for message in messages:
    hours, minutes, seconds = get_random_time()
    print(message + f' {hours}:{minutes}:{seconds}')
```